# Datepicker and Directives angular-ui bootstrap not working

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I generate an app with angular-fullstack and try to create Datepicker directives like this tutorial on angular-ui bootstrap: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker. but somehow i always get this error message with angular.js and my module DatePick.js on console browser:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < DatePick.js:2
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at eval (native)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:339:22
    at Function.jQuery.extend.globalEval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:340:7)
    at jQuery.fn.extend.domManip (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5931:16)
    at jQuery.fn.extend.append (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5704:15)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5830:18)
    at jQuery.access (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4108:8)
    at jQuery.fn.extend.html (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5794:10)
    at removePatch [as html] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2129:25)
    at link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:901:16) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

this is my module:

```
angular.module('vendorApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var DatepickerCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.showWeeks = true;
  $scope.toggleWeeks = function () {
    $scope.showWeeks = ! $scope.showWeeks;
  };

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = ( $scope.minDate ) ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
};
```

and my HTML:

```
<div class="input-append" ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">
<label><input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" /></label>
```

Comment: What is datepick.js  ?  I have this working in a plnkr...   http://plnkr.co/edit/vAJhLeB7raXz5qkQ39Qw?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Nix, oke, i generate module using coffee. that's make a file on scripts/controller/datepick.coffee and when i run my apps, some how DatePick.js come in as reference in build:js.

Comment: did you look at the plnkr above?   What differences are there in that code and yours?